# Is there a way to block the usage of a specific function from a package when linting in Go

Tags: go, static-analysis

Is there a semi-trivial way of blocking the usage of a specific function i.e `fmt.Sprintf` from a specific Go package when doing static analysis using something like golangci-lint or go/analysis.

Say you have package a:

```
package a

import "fmt"

func doStuff() {
    hello := fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", "hello world") // blocked and will throw a linting error
    fmt.Println(hello)
}
```

and package b:

```
package b

import "fmt"

func doMore() {
    hello := fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", "hello world") // allowed
    fmt.Println(hello)
}
```

And in package a the usage of fmt.Sprintf is banned.

Comment: In short: No, there isn't.

Comment: I've often wanted this, and have considered trying my hand at writing such a linter. Such a thing does not exist, AFAIK. The closest I have found is [depguard](https://github.com/OpenPeeDeeP/depguard), which blocks importing an entire package.